# How to add multiple numbers in dynamic list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've been searching and re-searching a lot on this and seem to be getting nowhere.

I have code that has a big list of data and when I click on an item the item forms a new list with a price. I'm trying to get the prices on the new list to form a total and I'm not very good with jQuery yet so I can only get so far as to display the first list items price and I am not sure how I can get it to loop through all of my `.textbox`'s to add all the numbers not just the first one only.

So here is what I have so far:

```
$('.itemproduct').click(function () {
    var product = $(this).find('.product').html();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').html();
    $("#list").append('<tr id="help">' + '<td>' + product + '</td>' + '<td class="move add">' + '<input type="text" class="textbox" value="' + price + '"/>' + '</td>' + '</tr>');
    var num = parseFloat($(".textbox").val());
    var new_num = $("#total").val(num.toFixed(2));
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Holas/8d74n/)

Comment: you want to add the total for that particular item only or for all the items. make the question a bit more clear.

Comment: here you want to make total value of all new added text boxes right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a variable that tracks the total, and iterate the textboxes to calculate the total, and then display the total in the '#total' box. As such:

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8d74n/4/

```
$('.itemproduct').click(function () 
{
    var product = $(this).find('.product').html();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').html();
    var total = 0.00;

    $("#list").append('<tr id="help">' + '<td>' + product + '</td>' + '<td class="move add">' + '<input type="text" class="textbox" value="' + price + '"/>' + '</td>' + '</tr>');

    $( '.textbox' ).each( function( ) 
    {
        var itemPrice = parseFloat( $( this ).val( ) );
        total += itemPrice;
    });

    total = total.toFixed( 2 );
    $( '#total' ).val( total );    
});
```

EDIT -----------

Was just fooling around with the fiddle and noticed that I got a rounding error, the total started to become numbers like '6.58999999999999999996' To account for this I added the line  'total = total.toFixed( 2 ); *also updated the fiddle version*

Comment: My issue I was facing was iterating the textboxes with .each, I've tried multiple times and couldn't get it to work :S

Comment: I looooooooove .each functions :D I use them all the time! Just keep in mind that if you are using it to modify a value that you instantiate the value you are modifying, ( total in this case ), outside of the .each loop.

Comment: I saw the rounding error right away :) and added the .toFixed(2) right to the last line:    $( '#total' ).val( total.toFixed(2) ); and it worked as well :D

Comment: Yep, it will work that way, but if you want to reference that value 'total' later, you will need to use toFixed again, which is why I chose to do it with an additional line :p

Comment: Ahhhh makes sence! Much smarter way of doing it thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
$('.itemproduct').click(function () {

    var product = $(this).find('.product').html();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').html();

    $("#list").append('<tr id="help">' + '<td>' + product + '</td>' + '<td class="move add">' + '<input type="text" class="textbox" value="' + price + '"/>' + '</td>' + '</tr>');

    var num = parseFloat($(".textbox").val());

    createTotal();    

});

function createTotal(){   
    var total = 0.0;
    $('#list tr').each(function(key, val){        
        total += parseFloat($(val).find('input').val());
    });
    $("#total").val(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8d74n/5/